# is it possible to number the output of a command in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ps, numbering

I'm in a Linux class and one of my assignment questions is to find out the total number of processes running on the server.

I have used the ps -aux command to list all the processes but I was wondering if there was a way to number the output so I can count them easier

Comment: Be conscious of the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)...

Comment: thanks for the help, I used the ps -aux | wc -l   command and that worked

Comment: As the answers say, piping to `wc-l` will give you the number of lines, but it's a good idea to suppress the header line with `ps -auxh`. Also, `ps -auxh | less -N` will allow you scroll the output with the lines enumerated.

Answer (score 2):

```
ps -aux | wc -l
```

Then subtract the number of lines used in the header and the footer of the command.

wc counts words but the -l counts lines

Comment: Have a look in the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ps)... `--no-headers` is handy

Answer (score 2):

Others have mentioned `wc -l` for producing a total line count... however there is also `nl` which might be more in keeping with your "*number the output*" question - it prepends line numbers:

```
$ ps -aux --no-headers | nl | head
     1  root         1  0.0  0.0  39872  7532 ?        Ss   Sep24   7:07 /sbin/init
     2  root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep24   0:02 [kthreadd]
     3  root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep24   0:44 [ksoftirqd/0]
     4  root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Sep24   0:00 [kworker/0:0H]
     5  root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep24  16:50 [rcu_sched]
     6  root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep24   0:00 [rcu_bh]
     7  root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep24   0:05 [migration/0]
     8  root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep24   0:04 [watchdog/0]
     9  root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep24   0:05 [watchdog/1]
    10  root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep24   0:05 [migration/1]
[...]
```

Comment: `| tail -n=1 | cut -d' ' -f1`   if added to the above will show you the number of the last line

Answer (score 1):

Try piping the output to the word count program, wc

```
ps -aux | wc -l
```

will give you the total number of lines outputted by the ps command.

Hope this helps.